# Comparing occurrences of a string in a list of lists to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists which has several string inside each list. I want to give an ID a item inside the list. Easier to explain by desired input and output.

Input (would be larger data set but with the same structure): 
[[u'ID1', u'Loreal', (u'Loreal', u'P&G'), 1, 2], [u'ID1', u'P&G', (u'Loreal', u'P&G'), 1, 2], [u'ID1', u'Loreal', (u'Loreal', u'Unilever'), 2, 1]]

Desire Output:
[[u'ID1', u'Loreal', (u'Loreal', u'P&G'), 1, 2,**1**], [u'ID1', u'P&G', (u'Loreal', u'P&G'), 1, 2, **2**], [u'ID1', u'Loreal', (u'Loreal', u'Unilever'), 2, 1, **1**]

The ID should be given according to the name of the company which is located in index 1 of each of the list. For example Loreal would be 1, P&G would be 2, etc.

My line of thought was to create a dictionary and check for each row if [1] is a key in the dictionary. If yes, add the value of that key(which would be the ID). Else, create a key-value pair in the dictionary of the key and ID(using a counter).

My code so far:

```
stageTwoDic = {}
dictionaryCounter = 1
for row in stageTwoList:
    for key in stageTwoDic:
        if key == row[1]:
            stageTwoList.append(stageTwoDic[row[1]])
    else:
        stageTwoDic[row[1]] = dictionaryCounter
        stageTwoList.append(dictionaryCounter)
        dictionaryCounter += 1
```

I get the follow error message:

```
 if key == row[1]:
 TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: is the numeric value of each company predefined or assigned on the fly? In other words, are the values stored in a database or something similar, or do you calculate and assign them as the function runs? If the former is the case (predefined values), putting them into a dictionary form, and then check with a `for` loop which company appears in index one of each sub-list should do the work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic issue in your code is that you are appending the integer (Counter) as a direct value to the `stageTwoList` , not as an element to its sublist (that is you should append it to `row` not `stageTwoList`) .

This causes the last element in `stageTwoList` to be the integer you appended, and hence when iteration reaches that element , `row` is `int` , and hence trying to do `row[1]` causes the error you are getting.

Also, you do not need to loop throw the keys in the dictionary to check if the key exists or not, you can use `in` operator for that.

You should instead do the following -

```
stageTwoDic = {}
dictionaryCounter = 1
for row in stageTwoList:
    if row[1] in stageTwoDic:
        row.append(stageTwoDic[row[1]])
    else:
        stageTwoDic[row[1]] = dictionaryCounter
        row.append(dictionaryCounter)
        dictionaryCounter += 1
```

Demo -

```
>>> stageTwoList = [[u'ID1', u'Loreal', (u'Loreal', u'P&G'), 1, 2], [u'ID1', u'P&G', (u'Loreal', u'P&G'), 1, 2], [u'ID1', u'Loreal', (u'Loreal', u'Unilever'), 2, 1]]
>>> stageTwoDic = {}
>>> dictionaryCounter = 1
>>> for row in stageTwoList:
...     if row[1] in stageTwoDic:
...         row.append(stageTwoDic[row[1]])
...     else:
...         stageTwoDic[row[1]] = dictionaryCounter
...         row.append(dictionaryCounter)
...         dictionaryCounter += 1
...
>>> stageTwoList
[['ID1', 'Loreal', ('Loreal', 'P&G'), 1, 2, 1], ['ID1', 'P&G', ('Loreal', 'P&G'), 1, 2, 2], ['ID1', 'Loreal', ('Loreal', 'Unilever'), 2, 1, 1]]
```

---

Just for sake of completion, another issue in your code was that you were actually updating the `stageTwoList` , even if `row[1]` was found in the dictionary because you did not have a `break` inside the `if` block. `else` part of a `for..else` construct would be executed if the the `for` loop exits normally (without a `break` statement or exception).